# Creating Multiple Clickable Divs with p5js

Tags: javascript, html, processing, p5.js

EDIT: I figured it out. I just went a totally different route, making a Button class and using rectangles on my actual canvas to represent them.

I am trying to make multiple clickable buttons programatically in p5js, and I am getting caught up on a problem.  All the divs are being created, they display and have the proper HTML associated with them, but no matter which is clicked only the last button's functionality is induced.

Here is a photo:
[image: rainbow buttons and a blank canvas]

Those are my buttons on the right, but no matter where you click, the color that is selected is always the purple at the bottom.

Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < colorCodes.length ; i++){
    var div = createDiv(str(i));
    div.parent('control-holder');
    div.style('background-color', colorCodes[i]);
    div.style('height', '40px');
    div.mousePressed(function(){
        console.log(div.html()); //always prints 7
        changeColor(int(div.html()));
    });
    buttons.push(div);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I don't understand why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common JavaScript trap.

When you use the `var` keyword, the variable you create has **function scope**, which means that the variable (in your case, your `i` variable) keeps its value until the end of the function, not until the end of the loop. Consider this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    console.log('i: ' + i);
}

console.log('final i: ' + i);
```

This code will print out 0-9 in the loop, and then will print out 10 after the loop exits.

Now, let's change the code a bit:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('i: ' + i);
    }, 1000);
}

console.log('final i: ' + i);
```

Now the loop sets up a timeout callback. This code will print out `final i: 10` first, and then will print out `i: 10` 10 times. This is because the `console.log('final i: ' + i);` line is happening **before** the callback functions are called. And since the variable has function scope, it takes the last value that it was given. Here's another example:

```
var i = 42;

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('i: ' + i);
}, 1000);

i = 37;
```

You might expect this code to print out `42`, but again, the callback function is being called **after** this code runs, so by the time it's called, `i` is `37`.

Anyway, back to your code. Hopefully the examples above show you what's happening in your code: the `var` keyword creates a function-scoped variable, which means that by the time your mousePressed callback is called, the variable holds the last value it was set to.

Traditionally, the way to get around this was to go through another function call:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    callSetTimeout(i);
}

console.log('final i: ' + i);

function callSetTimeout(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('i: ' + i);
    }, 1000);
}
```

But as of JavaScript 6, you can use the `let` keyword instead of `var`:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('i: ' + i);
    }, 1000);
}
```

This gives your variable **block scope** which means that the variable is only in-scope inside the `for` loop. As a result, each iteration of the loop gets its own copy, and your function will now work how you expected.